# How to add path of log4j.properties file in my project classpath in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, classpath

I have a package called Resources in which I have placed my log4j.properties file. When I run my code, I get the following error:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger.
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

How should I update the classpath to include Resource folder ?

Solution tried:
I added the log4j.properties file directly under 'source' and it worked.

Here is the contents of properties file:

```
#Application Logs
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=C:\\Users\\kagarwal\\Desktop\\Application.log
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

Comment: its just a warning. Can you paste the content of your `log4j.properties`? Also as i said its just a warning . logging must be happening depends on your config file.

Comment: Properties files has this:    #Application Logs
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=C:\\Users\\kagarwal\\Desktop\\Application.log
#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false

Comment: Also, my output file always stays blank.

Comment: Here is the full error message: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (devpinoyLogger). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: its difficult to read here. please move the code to question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the folder, select `Build Path` then `Use as a Source Folder`.

Just remember that when you will deploy you will need to create a directory for resources and add it to class path.

You should also consider to use maven for your java project, it may seem overkill initially but it will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks ! that worked like a charm. Yes, i will consider using maven going forward. I have just started learning Java, so taking baby steps.